# Pivot table into three level

Tags: python, dataframe, reshape

I have a data set like below in an excel -

[image]

I want to reshape the data as below -

[image]

I though pivot_table() function should work...but not able to create three levels of header. Also once the data is reshaped using pivot table, not able to rename the columns. 
Please suggest the necesasry steps (i.e. logic or if any function available). 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Pivotting and set your identifier column as index, swap level after pivot

```py
# df be your original dataframe
df = df.pivot_table(index=["SYMBOL", "NAME"], columns=["date"], values=["price", "price2"])
df.swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1). sort_index(axis=1)
```